# How to measure End2End Test coverage?

Tags: testing, code-coverage, karma-runner, angularjs-e2e

I used angularjs e2e for my project's end2end test i can also run that in karma.

I know i can use 'karma-coverage' plugin to measure my code coverage, but this is only for unit test.

Now, i want to measure End2End Test coverage which help me know how much my test cases have coverage scenario, Anyone can tell me how to measure end2end test coverage automatically?

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer is - it does not work out of the box.**

You can do it however:

1. The source files need to be preprocessed. With Angular Scenario Runner, Karma only proxies to your web server (it does not actually serve your app), so **you need to instrument the source files yourself.** Check out [Karma's coverage preprocessor](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage/blob/master/lib/preprocessor.js) and write a similar grunt script to preprocess the files that your web server serves.
2. Configure Karma to use `coverage` reporter as usual (`ng-scenario` adapter already knows how to send the results back to Karma).

Also, check out the discussion at https://groups.google.com/d/topic/karma-users/-YsEL96Wqds/discussion